# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else' while using else if

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make rock paper scissors in JS, everything is working but its showing error while using else if. My game gives you ten chances to play and the one who scores more points wins the game. Currently, I am trying to make this game play between computer and user 11 time. I tried using if statements for the conditions but I don't know why the computer only played two times and then I tried using else if and then this error was coming. My code is below-

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````
// rock paper scissor

const getRandom = (arr) => {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
};

console.log("Welcome to rock,paper and scissors. you will play against the computer.You will have ten chances to prove your worth")

let chances = 0

const arr = ["stone", "paper", "scissor"]
let rand = (getRandom(arr));

while (chances <= 11) {
  let inp = prompt("Please enter the value")

  if (inp == 'stone' && rand == 'scissor')
    console.log("you won")
    chances += 1
  console.log(chances)
  // ``````````````````````````````````````````````````````
  else if (inp == 'stone' && rand == 'paper')
    console.log("you lost")
  chances += 1
  console.log(chances)
  // ``````````````````````````````````````````````````````
  else if (inp == 'stone' && rand == 'stone')
    console.log("its a tie!!")
  chances += 1
  console.log(chances)
  // ``````````````````````````````````````````````````````  paper
  else if (inp == 'paper' && rand == 'scissor')
    console.log("you lost")
  chances += 1
  console.log(chances)
  // ``````````````````````````````````````````````````````  
  else if (inp == 'paper' && rand == 'stone')
    console.log("you won")
  chances += 1
  // ``````````````````````````````````````````````````````  
  else if (inp == 'paper' && rand == 'paper')
    console.log("its a tie")
  chances += 1
  // ``````````````````````````````````````````````````````  scissor
  else if (inp == 'scissor' && rand == 'stone')
    console.log("you lost")
  chances += 1
  // ``````````````````````````````````````````````````````  
  else if (inp == 'scissor' && rand == 'paper')
    console.log("you won")
  chances += 1
  // ``````````````````````````````````````````````````````  
  elseif (inp == 'scissor' && rand == 'scissor')
    console.log("its a tie")
  chances += 1
}
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````

The error is -

```
else if (inp == 'stone' && rand == 'paper')
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'
```

Comment: `elseif (inp == 'scissor' && rand == 'scissor')` at the end! it should be `else if ...` And you can put __only one__ statement without braces after and `for`, `while`, `if` and `else` statements.

Comment: this is why you always should enclose the body of an `if` with braces `{}` At least one of your if bodies (for instance the first one) consists of two statements

Comment: @derpirscher sorry at first I didn't notice that and found the `elseif` at the bottom and thought that was causing the error but soon after that I realized that the conditional statements are missing braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute more than one statement in an `if`, you need to create a block, using brackets (`{ … }`):

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````
if (inp == 'stone' && rand == 'scissor') {
    console.log("you won")
    chances += 1
    console.log(chances)
  // ``````````````````````````````````````````````````````
}
else if (inp == 'stone' && rand == 'paper') {
    console.log("you lost")
    chances += 1
    console.log(chances)
}
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````

More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else